# Ram upside down?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have a HP laptop and I recently bought another stick of RAM for it.

The slots look like this:

[image: The second slot is a mirror of the first one]

The original RAM is in the first slot but to place the other piece of RAM I have to turn it upside down so the notches line up. But when I did it didn't fit properly so I just removed the smaller original RAM and replaced it with the new RAM.

Is there any way I can have both RAM sticks installed?

Comment: It should fit just fine. What was wrong?

Comment: Also make sure both modules are from HP - works better.

Comment: the notches don't line up when the right way up but they do upside down, what do i do?

Comment: @John How so? Privately labeled RAM [labeled as HP, Dell, etc.] is no different than RAM labeled with the RAM's OEM's name. There are brand models that are better than others, but using RAM from a RAM OEM that's been privately labeled with the PC OEM's name doesn't make the RAM or system "work better". (Have some coffee =] )

Comment: The notches don’t line up, that sounds like you purchased DDR3 instead of DDR4 (or vice versa) as the notches are one of a few key differences between DDR3 and DDR4.  Please provide the complete and full specifications of both modules in English

Comment: There is no "up side down" when it comes to ram, either is fits or it doesn't.

Comment: @Moab what do you mean, I thought that the side where the black squares where the top, can you place them facing down?

Comment: @JW - By "work better" I meant ONLY fit. I was not referring to electrical characteristics.

Comment: @user1284208 " can you place them facing down? " Yes, I see this all the time in laptops, as long as it fits the slot it is in correctly, different ram has the slot in a different place so you cannot install the incorrect ram.

Comment: What are the specifications of the computer and the RAM stick?